# fast-import crash: Invalid raw date

Tags: python-3.x, git, github-pages, pelican

I'm trying to use the [ghp-import](https://github.com/davisp/ghp-import) tool to import into a master branch, but I keep getting `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

The crash report says

> fatal: Invalid raw date "1576064213 India Standard Time" in ident: Rabbani  1576064213 India Standard Time

Moreover the file that I am trying to import was created by pelican using the command

```
pelican content
```

Pelican is a python framework to generate static sites. The metadata for posts includes the date as

```
Date: 2019-12-11 20:00
```

I ran the command

```
ghp-import output -b master
```

which results in the error above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the ghp-import repo related to this: [link](https://github.com/davisp/ghp-import/issues/60).

The underlying problem identified in that ticket is that the Python 2 `time.strftime()` function does not share the same format strings as Python 3's `time.strftime()`, leading to bad formatting of the date.

What version of Python are you using? Please include the output of these two commands:

```
python --version
python -c 'import pelican; print(pelican.__version__)
```

If it is possible, I recommend setting up a virtual environment with Python 3 (here, 3.6):

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 vp && source vp/bin/activate
```

Then you'll be using Python 3 and the problem should be resolved.